# How to trigger a directive within ngIf once ngIf finishes rendering html elements?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, lifecycle, angular-ng-if

My problem involves the *ngif directive when once *ngif=true I want the html content to render first before my 'ModClass' directive can do its stuff.

I tried to implement ngOnInit and ngViewInit but no luck since I believe ngOnInit triggers while ngif content is being rendered or maybe earlier when the parent component is generated.

Also for ngViewInit I think I need to be subscribed to something but I don't know exactly what I need to be subscribed to. (I might be completely wrong about this will do more research)

The following code illustrates my problem along with having a stacksblitz link so you won't have to recreate this code on your machine to troubleshoot.

What the code is suppose to do is on button click it toggles a boolean variable that is used with the ngIf as so: ***ngIf='trigger'**

The ngIf code will display a div block with default css class 'red' but my directive will change it to the 'blue' class.

**UPDATE**

Turns out ngViewInit would work fine as long as I use ElementRef.
Thanks for all the help.

Directive in src/app/modify-class/modify-class.directive

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: 'ModClass'
})
export class ModifyClassDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor (private htmlElement: HTMLElement) {}

  //should i try ngViewinit instead
  ngOnInit () {
    this.activateThisClass()
  }

  /*ngViewInit () {
    this.activateThisClass()
  }*/
  //this function should execute once ng-if condition is true and html is rendered
  activateThisClass () {
    console.log('i\'ve been triggered')
    const list = this.htmlElement.getElementsByClassName('red')
    list.forEach(element => element.classList.remove('red'))
    list.forEach(element => element.classList.add('blue'))
  }
}
```

HTML/Hello Component content found in src/app/hello.component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  <button ModClass='' (click)="trigger=!trigger;"> click me </button>

<div *ngIf='trigger'> 

  <!-- This is what i want to change once it is rendered -->
  <div ModClass='' class='red'> this will/should be overwritten and turn blue </div>

</div>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() trigger: boolean;

  constructor() {this.trigger = false}
}
```

linkt to [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directivecall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you intend to use the directive as described in the question (since the `red` class appears to be applied only when the element doesn't exist) but here are two things that you can change to make it work:

- Change the directive [selector](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#build-a-simple-attribute-directive) from `ModClass` to `[ModClass]`
- Inject `ElementRef` in the directive constructor instead of `HTMLElement`

Here is the modified code:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[ModClass]'
})
export class ModifyClassDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor (private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit () {
    this.activateThisClass()
  }

  activateThisClass () {
    console.log("activateThisClass triggered!")
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    element.classList.remove('red');
    element.classList.add('blue');
  }
}
```

See [the modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directivecall-3kbk8f).

Comment: What I wrote was a simplified version of what I'm working on but your recommendation of injecting ElementRef was what I needed to do to use in ngViewInit() function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your code:

```
<button (click)="trigger=!trigger;"> click me </button>

<div *ngIf='trigger'> 
  <!-- This is what i want to change once it is rendered -->
  <div ModClass class='red'> this will/should be overwritten and turn blue </div>
```

And your directive should be like:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[ModClass]' // changed
})
export class ModifyClassDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor (private el: ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit () {
    this.activateThisClass()
  }
  activateThisClass () {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

For more details for custom directive go through this link :[Custome directive](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/creating-a-custom-directive/)

You can do the same in ngAfterViewInit As well.